# Access/Get Reference of an already-existing UIViewController (Simulating Back Button)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an iOS application that I started from scratch. I do not want to use a UINavigationController nor a UITabController for design reasons. I will include a back button on one of my UIViewControllers. The back button should take me back to the previous UIViewController without instantiating a new one. **So I am looking for a method to get a reference of the already-existing UIViewController** so I can use presentController method with it.

Any help, suggestion will be much appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your design paradigm is flawed - UINavigationControllers are excellent and can be customised.

However you simply need to pass a reference to your previous VC forward to your child VC on instantiation.

Comment: It is weird how I did not think of passing the VC as a property. Thanks, and I will try to use a navigation controller next.

Comment: Sure no problem - I often have writers block with code too! If you need further help SO is here :)